# Facebook c# mvc4 retrieve password?

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I got all information I need for a facebook registration to my database, except a password. How is the user going to get registered if I cant get access to their password? 
any ideas?

```
newUser.Alias = User.FbEmail;
newUser.UserName = User.FbEmail;
newUser.EMail = User.FbEmail;
newUser.Password = "password";
newUser.BirthDate = _defaultNoDate;
```

Answer (score 3):

You will never get a password from Facebook Api. Facebook provides you with an Access Token that allows you to handle your user information